# Overriding Spring property place holders in Mule functional tests

Tags: mule

I am testing my Mule application and need to override some of the property values with ones for testing purposes. What is the best way to do this for Mule functional tests? BTW I am using Maven.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leverage Spring's overriding mechanism:

```
<context:property-placeholder
    ignore-resource-not-found="true"
    location="classpath:default.properties,classpath:override.properties" />
```

With `src/main/resources/default.properties` defining the default properties values and `src/test/resources/override.properties` defining the overrides.

Answer (score 0):

Also below solution is helpful.

```
<context:property-placeholder local-override="true" 
location="persistence.properties"/>
```

And in have file like below with overridden peroperties :

```
test/resources/persistence-override.properties
```

Please notice to word **"override"** in file name.